# hover and float element

Tags: html, css

last week I coding a menu bar for my blog at http://iHMahmoodi.blog.ir
but for social buttons it's going to wrong and I think it's about float element!
I try to fix it with adding some width or more property but it's not work!
you can do it yourself with inspect element on my blog.
look to below image of my blog to know about my problem

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntjIH.png

another question is near the rss image it's broad a lot of space on the right hand and if move you mouse between phone number and social button, all about rss!!

thanks a lot!

Comment: Please add the relevant part of your code that is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will make them equal size and it list-image fits right to text**

**Edit** with paddings you get your icons like picture below.

```
li.fb,
li.fb li {    
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 150px;
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks EspeH I added your code and they goes equal size, but text of each button not be in the line beside of their icons! look to image below http://i.cubeupload.com/YVQwqY.jpg   and it's so tall :D (it's need to be smaller)

Comment: here my code <pre> <code>ul.imenu li{
 list-style-position: inside  ; 
}

ul.imenu li.fb{
  padding-left: 15px;  
 list-style-image: url('http://bayanbox.ir/download/1594173205959174434/facebook.ico')  ; 
    
}




li.fb,
li.fb li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 150px;
 
}
 
ul.imenu li.tw{
 list-style-image: url('http://bayanbox.ir/download/3458378730242649411/twitter.ico')  ; 
 padding-left: 15px; 
 
}

ul.imenu li.lin{
    padding-left: 15px;
 list-style-image: url('http://bayanbox.ir/download/7335656936120790444/linkedin.ico')   ;
    
}
</code></pre>

Comment: I edited my answer to fix that icon issue, picture updated too. :)